# Reshape input layer 'requested shape' size always 'input shape' size squared

Tags: tensorflow, predict, c-api

I am trying to run a SavedModel using the C-API.
When it comes to running `TF_SessionRun` it always fails on various input nodes with the same error.

```
TF_SessionRun status: 3:Input to reshape is a tensor with 6 values, but the requested shape has 36
TF_SessionRun status: 3:Input to reshape is a tensor with 19 values, but the requested shape has 361
TF_SessionRun status: 3:Input to reshape is a tensor with 3111 values, but the requested shape has 9678321
...
```

As can be seen, the number of requested shape values is always the square of the expected input size. It's quite odd.

The model runs fine with the `saved_model_cli` command.
The inputs are all either scalar DT_STRING or DT_FLOATs, I'm not doing image recogition.
Here's the output of that command:

`signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['f1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: f1:0
    inputs['f2'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: f2:0
    inputs['f3'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: f3:0
    inputs['f4'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1)
        name: f4:0
    inputs['f5'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: f5:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['o1_probs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_DOUBLE
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: output_probs:0
    outputs['o1_values'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: output_labels:0
    outputs['predicted_o1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: output_class:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict`

Any clues into what's going on are much appreciated. The saved_model.pb file is coming from AutoML, my code is merely querying that model. I don't change the graph.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was caused by me not using the TF_AllocateTensor function correctly.

The original code was like:

```
TF_Tensor* t = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_STRING, nullptr, 0, sz);
```

when it appears it should have been:

```
int64_t dims = 0;
TF_Tensor* t = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_STRING, &dims, 1, sz);
```